# Restful Java application with spring security OAuth 2.0 library

Tags: java, spring-security, jersey, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I am developing RESTFUL Java application in this i use JERSEY library. In my application i have to authenticate user with spring security OAuth 2.0 library. I am in need of both provider and client. I have searched lot in internet.

Can any one share a simple example or any nice tutorial with basic steps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you specifically need Spring Security library for OAuth 2.0 or would it be possible for you to use OAuth 2.0 support from Jersey?

Comment: No i need spring security for handling sessions. Is it possible to handle with jersey

Comment: Michal@: Need spring security with oauth 2.0 implementation for my jersey webservice